# Please fix my issue - cannot resolve method

Tags: android

The problems are there in `set()`,`before()`,`set Hours()`,`set Minutes()` depicting cannot resolve command,as i am making android application for a book with daily different phrase notification at specific time.please send me source code to rectify my mistakes and explain about them.

```
import static java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY;

import static java.util.Calendar.MINUTE;

import static java.util.Calendar.getInstance;

         if(calendar.before(System.currentTimeMillis())){
                calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);

                Calendar calendar = null;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    calendar = getInstance();
                    calendar.set(HOUR_OF_DAY,24);
                    calendar.set(MINUTE,00);

                    if(calendar.before(System.currentTimeMillis())){
                        calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                    }

                }else{
                    date = new Date();
                    date.setHours(24);
                    date.setMinutes(0);
                }

            }
```

Comment: Could you at least specify the errors you get? What <b>exactly</b> is the issue you encounter?

Comment: Those commands I specified are showing error cannot resolve command and

Answer (score 0):

Check the import line for `Calender` and `Date`:

It should be:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
```

And Not:

```
import android.icu.util.Calendar;
import java.sql.Date;
```

Comment: import android.icu.util.Calendar;
import java.sql.Date; these command I haven't mentioned

Comment: Add `import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;` at start of file, will fix the issue

Comment: Hmm...added then also issue remains please suggest other solution